# "Key group is not in KeyGroupRange" Error when joining two streams based on event time in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a simple test to join two streams by the event time:

```
 @Test
void testJoinStream() {
    var settings = EnvironmentSettings
            .newInstance()
            .inStreamingMode()
            .build();
    var tableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
    var configuration = tableEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setString("table.exec.resource.default-parallelism", "2");

    var testTable = tableEnv.from(TableDescriptor.forConnector("datagen")
            .schema(Schema.newBuilder()
                    .column("ts", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3))
                    .column("v", DataTypes.INT())
                    .watermark("ts", "ts - INTERVAL '1' second")
                    .build())
            .option(DataGenConnectorOptions.ROWS_PER_SECOND, 2L)
            .option("fields.v.kind", "sequence")
            .option("fields.v.start", "0")
            .option("fields.v.end", "1000000")
            .build());
    testTable.printSchema();
    tableEnv.createTemporaryView("test", testTable );

    var joined = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT ts, v, v2 from test" +
            " join (SELECT ts as ts2, v as v2 from test) on ts = ts2");

    try {
        var tableResult = joined.executeInsert(TableDescriptor.forConnector("print").build());
        tableResult.await();

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

It failed within a few seconds:

```
(
  `ts` TIMESTAMP(3) *ROWTIME*,
  `v` INT,
  WATERMARK FOR `ts`: TIMESTAMP(3) AS ts - INTERVAL '1' second
)
1> +I[2021-11-16T17:48:24.415, 1, 1]
1> +I[2021-11-16T17:48:24.415, 0, 1]
1> +I[2021-11-16T17:48:24.415, 1, 0]
1> +I[2021-11-16T17:48:24.415, 0, 0]

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at com.microstrategy.realtime.FlinkTest.testJoinStream(FlinkTest.java:123)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.awaitInternal(TableResultImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.await(TableResultImpl.java:92)
    at com.microstrategy.realtime.FlinkTest.testJoinStream(FlinkTest.java:120)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Failed to wait job finish
    at app//org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultIterator.hasNext(InsertResultIterator.java:56)
    at app//org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(TableResultImpl.java:370)
    at app//org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.isFirstRowReady(TableResultImpl.java:383)
    at app//org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.lambda$awaitInternal$1(TableResultImpl.java:116)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.InsertResultIterator.hasNext(InsertResultIterator.java:54)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:137)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:250)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at app//org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.doForward(FutureUtils.java:1389)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$null$1(ClassLoadingUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$guardCompletionWithContextClassLoader$2(ClassLoadingUtils.java:92)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$1.onComplete(AkkaFutureUtils.java:47)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:300)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:297)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:221)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.AkkaFutureUtils$DirectExecutionContext.execute(AkkaFutureUtils.java:65)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.$anonfun$tryComplete$1$adapted(Promise.scala:284)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:284)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:621)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:24)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:23)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$andThen$1(Future.scala:532)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:228)
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:218)
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:209)
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:679)
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
    at app//org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:444)
    at java.base@11.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key group 11 is not in KeyGroupRange{startKeyGroup=64, endKeyGroup=127}. Unless you're directly using low level state access APIs, this is most likely caused by non-deterministic shuffle key (hashCode and equals implementation).
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupRangeOffsets.newIllegalKeyGroupException(KeyGroupRangeOffsets.java:37)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTable.getMapForKeyGroup(StateTable.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTable.get(StateTable.java:261)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.StateTable.get(StateTable.java:143)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.heap.HeapMapState.iterator(HeapMapState.java:161)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.UserFacingMapState.iterator(UserFacingMapState.java:95)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.join.interval.TimeIntervalJoin.processElement1(TimeIntervalJoin.java:171)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.join.interval.RowTimeIntervalJoin.processElement1(RowTimeIntervalJoin.java:26)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.join.interval.TimeIntervalJoin.processElement1(TimeIntervalJoin.java:51)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.KeyedCoProcessOperator.processElement1(KeyedCoProcessOperator.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.processRecord1(StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.lambda$create$0(StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.java:183)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:134)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamMultipleInputProcessor.processInput(StreamMultipleInputProcessor.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:496)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:203)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:809)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:761)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:937)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

What is the problem? The error message is not intuitive and I couldn't find what caused the problem.

I saw the Exception is reported by others such as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18637 . But those are using DataStream APIs.
I logged this one as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24926

Updated:
Query Plan

```
== Abstract Syntax Tree ==
LogicalProject(ts=[$0], v=[$1], v2=[$3])
+- LogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $2)], joinType=[inner])
   :- LogicalWatermarkAssigner(rowtime=[ts], watermark=[-($0, 1000:INTERVAL SECOND)])
   :  +- LogicalTableScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, Unnamed_TableDescriptor$1]])
   +- LogicalProject(ts2=[$0], v2=[$1])
      +- LogicalWatermarkAssigner(rowtime=[ts], watermark=[-($0, 1000:INTERVAL SECOND)])
         +- LogicalTableScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, Unnamed_TableDescriptor$1]])

== Optimized Physical Plan ==
Calc(select=[ts, v, v0 AS v2])
+- IntervalJoin(joinType=[InnerJoin], windowBounds=[isRowTime=true, leftLowerBound=0, leftUpperBound=0, leftTimeIndex=0, rightTimeIndex=0], where=[=(ts, ts0)], select=[ts, v, ts0, v0])
   :- Exchange(distribution=[hash[ts]])
   :  +- WatermarkAssigner(rowtime=[ts], watermark=[-(ts, 1000:INTERVAL SECOND)])
   :     +- TableSourceScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, Unnamed_TableDescriptor$1]], fields=[ts, v])
   +- Exchange(distribution=[hash[ts]])
      +- WatermarkAssigner(rowtime=[ts], watermark=[-(ts, 1000:INTERVAL SECOND)])
         +- TableSourceScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, Unnamed_TableDescriptor$1]], fields=[ts, v])

== Optimized Execution Plan ==
Calc(select=[ts, v, v0 AS v2])
+- IntervalJoin(joinType=[InnerJoin], windowBounds=[isRowTime=true, leftLowerBound=0, leftUpperBound=0, leftTimeIndex=0, rightTimeIndex=0], where=[(ts = ts0)], select=[ts, v, ts0, v0])
   :- Exchange(distribution=[hash[ts]])(reuse_id=[1])
   :  +- WatermarkAssigner(rowtime=[ts], watermark=[(ts - 1000:INTERVAL SECOND)])
   :     +- TableSourceScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, Unnamed_TableDescriptor$1]], fields=[ts, v])
   +- Reused(reference_id=[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Flink 1.14.0. I left it running for several minutes; it worked fine. On 1.14, EXPLAIN

```
EXPLAIN select ts, v, v2 from test join (select ts as ts2, v as v2 from test) on ts = ts2

== Optimized Execution Plan ==
Calc(select=[ts, v, v0 AS v2])
+- IntervalJoin(joinType=[InnerJoin], windowBounds=[isRowTime=true, leftLowerBound=0, leftUpperBound=0, leftTimeIndex=0, rightTimeIndex=0], where=[(ts = ts0)], select=[ts, v, ts0, v0])
   :- Exchange(distribution=[hash[ts]])(reuse_id=[1])
   :  +- WatermarkAssigner(rowtime=[ts], watermark=[(ts - 1000:INTERVAL SECOND)])
   :     +- TableSourceScan(table=[[vvp, default, test]], fields=[ts, v])
   +- Reused(reference_id=[1])
```

shows that the planner is understanding this as an interval join. This is important: streaming joins can easily become pathological unless the runtime can optimize them by exploiting some sort of temporal constraint.

Perhaps you are using an earlier version of Flink SQL, and it is producing a different plan for this query?

Comment: I’m using 1.14.0, too. Let me check my query plan and dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: Hi David, I check the query plan and it looks the same as you posted. I also tried it on Mac, Windows, and a Linux cluster. I put my code as well as the the Gradle file in this repo: https://github.com/liuhb86/flink24926

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that will be fixed in Flink 1.15.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-24926 and
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19792.